# How to replace repeating characters with the same number of asterisks?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to replace the repeated characters with the *same number* of asterisks (*).

For example:

```
replaceLetters("keviin");
```

Should return:

> kev**n

And:

```
replaceLetters("haaa");
```

Should return:

> h***

How can I go about doing this?

If I use the following code it does replace the repeating characters, but it replaces the whole repetition with one asterisk instead of the same number of asterisks as repeating characters.

```js
function replaceLetters(s) {
    s.replace(/([^])\1+/g, '*');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.replace()` allows a function to be passed as the second argument. The argument for the callback function passed will be the matched string. Once you have access to the matched string, there are any number of ways you can replace the matched string with the same number of asterisks.

For example, you could turn the string into an array, use map to replace each array item with an asterisk and join the array back together as a string.

```
function replaceLetters(s) { 
    return s.replace(/([^])\1+/g,function(m) { 
        return m.split('').map(function(){ return '*' }).join(''); 
    }); 
}
```

Or you could replace every character in the matched string with an asterisk.

```
function replaceLetters(s) { 
    return s.replace(/([^])\1+/g,function(m) { 
        return m.replace(/[^]/g,'*'); 
    });
}
```

There are many ways you could go about this, it all depends on how you want to accomplish the task.

Comment: Well, everything is also not nothing. @torazaburo